# How to perform SQL batch updates in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following to perform a batch update in Azure table storage using Azure.Data.Tables:

```
public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
{            
    var batchOperation = new List<TableTransactionAction>();

    if (users.Count() <= 100)
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {

            batchOperation.Add(new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.UpdateMerge, user));
        }

        if (batchOperation.Any())
        {
            await _tableClient.SubmitTransactionAsync(batchOperation);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I perform a similar batch update in Azure SQL table using Entity Framework?

```
public class DatabaseRepo
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;
    
    public DatabaseRepo(UserContext userContext)
    {
        _context = userContext;
    }        

    public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {            
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using? EF6? EF Core? 1.x? 6.x? 7.x? Are you wanting to do a "blind" `UPDATE` - or do you want to load-then-edit-then-save? Do you want to ensure consistency with a concurrency-token and/or verify unmodified fields? How are you initially populating the `users` passed into `BatchUpdateUsersAsync` ?

Comment: EFCore 6.x, blind update works

Comment: Can you update to EFCore 7? [EFC7 adds `ExecuteUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7) which is better than the alternative (where you have to attach entities)

Comment: Unfortunately, I see some issues while updating to EFCore 7. Need a solution that works on EFCore 6.

Answer (score 0):

Ef Core does [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#batching) automatically.

> The number of statements that EF batches in a single roundtrip depends on the database provider being used. For example, performance analysis has shown batching to be generally less efficient for SQL Server when less than 4 statements are involved. Similarly, the benefits of batching degrade after around 40 statements for SQL Server, so EF Core will by default only execute up to 42 statements in a single batch, and execute additional statements in separate roundtrips.

Just attach all the entities as Modified and run SaveChanges().  EG

```
public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
{

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var entry = dbContext.Set<User>().Add(user);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You can do this generically on your DbContext like this:

```
public async Task BatchUpdate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T: class
{

    foreach (var user in entities)
    {
        var entry = this.Set<T>().Add(user);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    await this.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to use a for loop to update each user?

Comment: In a loop you only add them to the DbContext's change tracker.  Then SaveChanges batches the updates to the database. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is it similar to do a batch call to get/delete users? Can you please give an example for both?

Comment: Batch "get" is just an EF query loaded to a `List<T>` with .ToList().  Delete is similar to Update.  Search the web for "EF controller samples".